# Removing characters from list containing tuples

Tags: python

I have a list of tuples. I want to get rid of first 2 chars and last char of all first tuple elements.

```
db=[("b'D967E735-070D-48F9-A3BB-D00766D39F57'", 'test1', '51-00401'), 
("b'94F903D1-2EE7-4BD2-A0C6-B464D9F2939C'", 'Ddfsd_test4', '51-00404'), 
("b'FE0CC34C-BA6A-4123-B72C-617ADC0A93E7'", 'Xdsfd_test10', '51-00409'), 
("b'43996819-A615-4DC8-BB93-C4A54007FB34'", 'dsd', '51-00453'), 
("b'15D1B5DA-2E1D-4D86-9E53-60F3257D81E1'", 'dsd', '60-00400')]
```

it should return as below (b' and ' has been removed from every first tuple element)

```
db=[("D967E735-070D-48F9-A3BB-D00766D39F57", 'test1', '51-00401'), 
("94F903D1-2EE7-4BD2-A0C6-B464D9F2939C", 'Ddfsd_test4', '51-00404'), 
("FE0CC34C-BA6A-4123-B72C-617ADC0A93E7", 'Xdsfd_test10', '51-00409'), 
("43996819-A615-4DC8-BB93-C4A54007FB34", 'dsd', '51-00453'), 
("15D1B5DA-2E1D-4D86-9E53-60F3257D81E1", 'dsd', '60-00400')]
```

tried below but got TypeError: 'tuple' object is not callable

```
for i in db:
   y=list(map(i[2:len(i[0])-1],i[0]))
print (y)
```

Comment: Do you know why it writes a `b` prefix in the first place?

Comment: Wait, how did something like this: `"b'D967E735-070D-48F9-A3BB-D00766D39F57'"` come to be? It looks like someone called `str` on a `bytes` object... the best solution is to *fix that*

Comment: Do you know why it writes a b prefix in the first place?
it is a return value form a database query.

Comment: It also appears that you don't know how `map()` works. The way you're trying to call it makes no sense. I agree with the previous commenters that you should fix this problem upstream somewhere, but if you change your code to: `y = map(lambda i: (i[0][2:-1], i[1], i[2]), db)` it should work.

Comment: or decompose your tuple in a list comprehension:  
y = [(x[0][2:len(x[0])-1], x[1], x[2]) for x in db]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just a little bit of list comprehension:

```
res = [((x[0][2:-1], x[1], x[2])) for x in db]
```

Comment: For those that prefer fewer subscripts: `[(x[2:-1], y, z) for (x, y, z) in db]`

Answer (score 2):

I agree with @juanpa.arrivillaga's comment, you should fix a bad output of a function if you can modify it. But if you can't, this solution would work.

```
import ast

db=[("b'D967E735-070D-48F9-A3BB-D00766D39F57'", 'test1', '51-00401'), 
("b'94F903D1-2EE7-4BD2-A0C6-B464D9F2939C'", 'Ddfsd_test4', '51-00404'), 
("b'FE0CC34C-BA6A-4123-B72C-617ADC0A93E7'", 'Xdsfd_test10', '51-00409'), 
("b'43996819-A615-4DC8-BB93-C4A54007FB34'", 'dsd', '51-00453'), 
("b'15D1B5DA-2E1D-4D86-9E53-60F3257D81E1'", 'dsd', '60-00400')]

new_db = []

for thing, name, code in db:
    thing = ast.literal_eval(thing).decode()
    new_db.append((thing, name, code))

print(new_db)
```

Basically, this solutions takes the entry, reads it as a bytes object (using [ast.literal_eval()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval)). Then converts it to a string object (using [bytes.decode()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#bytes.decode)). I think this is a more natural solution than just removing the first two, and the last character.

Comment: Good.  It's important to more explicitly call out that what was missed is that someone called `str(thing)` rather than `thing.decode()` somewhere upstream.  The OP would be well advised to look for where his bytes object was cast to string and decode it instead.

Answer (score 0):

You are using `map` incorrectly. The first parameter has to be a function or a lambda. `i[2:len(i[0])-1]` is neither. So you can either define a function that does the same thing, i.e.:

```
def removeFirstAndLast(theString):
    return theString[2:len(theString[0])-1]
for i in db:
    y=list(removeFirstAndLast,i[0]))
print (y)
```

Or just use an inline lambda:

```
for i in db:
    y=list(map(lambda x: x[2:len(x[0])-1],i[0]))
print (y)
```